# Delete millions of rows on a badly designed table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have identified Millions of duplicated rows on a table I have inherited by using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumRecords, AccessID, LEFT(SQLTEXT, 5000)
FROM Table
WHERE AccessID=5012
GROUP BY AccessID, LEFT(SQLTEXT, 5000)
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

[image]

The only index I can use on the table is the AccessRequestID field - the SQLText field is VARCHAR(MAX) and there are over 100 million records here and since there is a varchar(MAX) column the table is *HUGE* and takes FOREVER to do anything with.  How can I turn that Select statement into a delete to remove the duplicated records?  I was trying to figure out how the write a CTE using Partition Rownum, but I'm not confident in it.  My Idea would be to have it in a loop that starts with AccessID 1 and then increments by one until the end of the table (There are only 5012 unique accessIDs)  Since I would be filtering the where by the NC Index it will hopefully be faster.

Comment: [Take Care When Scripting Batches](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)

Comment: It gets me on the right track, the main problem is having hundreds of millions of records + VarcharMAX columns and how to effectively get rid of the duplication.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try to insert the valid rows into a new table and then replace the old table with the new one.

Comment: I would not really be opposed to this, but same question - Looking at the data above, how would I script one insert from each "set" that I want to keep?

Comment: Use the [SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) and use a SELECT DISTINCT statement. Make sure that no SQLTEXT is longer than 5000, otherwise you might create duplicates by truncating the text. Using a loop is certainly the slowest option.

Comment: Thank you - this is the way I went with it....